# Displaying Amount from jcombobox

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have a very simple table in mysql, I was able to display all the names on the table to the combo box but I would like to display the equivalent amount on a field. There seems to be no runtime error but nothing happens, please help.

[image]

I added the method upon clicking on the ADD ITEM. Here are my codes for the add item and for the method of getting the amount from the combo box.

```
     private void InsertbtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {

   String sql = "Insert into item (NAME,AMOUNT) values (?,?)";

   pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   String value  = INSERTdrp.getSelectedItem().toString();
   pst.setString(1,value);

   pst.setString(2, AMOUNTfld.getText());

   pst.execute();





} catch (SQLException ex ) {
    System.out.println("error connecting" + ex );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Query Failed");





 }
        AMOUNTfld.setText("");

    updateCombo();
      amountPull();
      update_Table();
```

For pulling  the amount

```
         private void amountPull() {

         try {


        String query  = "select * from item";
        st = con.prepareStatement(query);


        String value  = INSERTdrp.getSelectedItem().toString();
       pst.setString(1,value);


    rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()) {
       String amount = rs.getString("AMOUNT"); 
        amountDisplay.setText(amount);

        }

    } catch(SQLException ex) {

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
    }}
```

Here are the other part of my code

```
    private void fillCombo() {

     try {


        String query  = "select * from item";
        st = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);


        while(rs.next()) {
       String name = rs.getString("NAME"); 
        INSERTdrp.addItem(name);

        }

    } catch(Exception ex) {

    }}

   private void updateCombo() {

        INSERTdrp.removeAllItems();


       try {


        String query  = "select * from item";
        st = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);


        while(rs.next()) {
       String name = rs.getString("NAME"); 
        INSERTdrp.addItem(name);

        }

    } catch(SQLException ex) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);

    } 

    }



       private void update_Table() {

       try {

        String query  = "select * from item";
        st = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        tableList.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));




    } catch(SQLException ex) {

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);

    } 


   }
```

Comment: Where's combobox? Looks like a `JTable` and a `JTextArea` to me

Comment: I'm assume you're trying to sum the results, not just display each row

Comment: that is actually my main objective, but for me to do that, I will need to pull those numbers on the "AMOUNT" which corresponds to the "NAME". Once I get them, Im thinking of manipulating those numbers to do add,subtract etc. Then once I get my result, I will update the table and erase the "AMOUNT" then replace it with the sum.

Comment: @MadProgrammer INSERTdrp is the combo box, for the table, simply tablelist is the name

Comment: @MadProgrammer  that is actually my main objective, but for me to do that, I will need to pull those numbers on the "AMOUNT" which corresponds to the "NAME". Once I get them, Im thinking of manipulating those numbers to do add,subtract etc. Then once I get my result, I will update the table and erase the "AMOUNT" then replace it with the sum

Comment: It's "Java" not "JAVA". Additionally the tag should indicate as such so there's no need to repeat it in the title.